# Swift list / delete all files in documents directory with progress

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to list (and later delete) all the files in the documents directory of my iOS app. Also I would like to use a Progress var to show progress (may be >1000 files). and Log "now deleteing file (fileName)"

```
extension FileManager {
    func urls(for directory: FileManager.SearchPathDirectory, skipsHiddenFiles: Bool = true ) -> [URL]? {
        let documentsURL = urls(for: directory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
        let fileURLs = try? contentsOfDirectory(at: documentsURL, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: skipsHiddenFiles ? .skipsHiddenFiles : [] )
        return fileURLs
    }
}
```

The previous code list 3 folders in the documents directory (correct) but how do I get the list of all files in those folders and subfolders. I think I would need the total number of files for the totalUnitCount of the Progress object that will be used, right?

Comment: You are supposed to only ask one question at a time. Note that there is no need to delete each file individually. You can simply delete the whole folders and recreate them.

Comment: Btw using `FileManager.SearchPathDirectory` inside a `FileManager` extension is redundant/pointless. `func urls(for directory: SearchPathDirectory, ...`

Comment: and how do I show deletion progress?